# Media added with shortcodes not "linked" with post

Tags: shortcode, post-editor

When you add Mediafiles (images, galleries, videos etc.) with the "Add Media Screen" in "Post Edit Screen" then the Attachment will get linked(parent_id) to the post/page.

I don't know if this is done while you select the Mediafile from the Library or after saving the post?

The problem is, I have created a shortcode which adds media to my post but those Mediafiles do not get linked to the post.

Has anyone an idea how to fix that?

tnx

Comment: when you call `media_handle_upload` the 2nd argument must be the post identifier to link the post to the media : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload

Comment: @mmm tnx for your hint, i searched and found out that the best way would be with the Ajax-API https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins. in combination with this https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media